# Buildroot plugin file is compiled for the target architecture altough used later in Makefile

Tags: makefile, cross-compiling, automake, buildroot

I am trying to create an package for dietsplash for buildroot, and I've added the files

Config.in

```
config BR2_PACKAGE_DIETSPLASH
    bool "dietsplash"
    help
        dietsplash is an simple splash screen service for
        embedded devices. It has support for animations.
```

dietsplash.mk

```
################################################################################
#
# dietsplash
#
################################################################################

DIETSPLASH_VERSION = v0.3
DIETSPLASH_SOURCE = dietsplash-$(DIETSPLASH_VERSION).tar.gz
DIETSPLASH_SITE = git://github.com/lucasdemarchi/dietsplash.git
DIETSPLASH_AUTORECONF = YES

$(eval $(autotools-package))
```

The github repository is 
https://github.com/lucasdemarchi/dietsplash

The output of make is:

```
>>> dietsplash v0.3 Building
PATH="/media/justus_fluegel/PROJECTS/buildroot/buildroot-2019.11.1/output/host/bin:/media/justus_fluegel/PROJECTS/buildroot/buildroot-2019.11.1/output/host/sbin:/home/justus_fluegel/.pub-cache/bin/:/usr/share/flutter/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/:/usr/share/flutter/flutter/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/snap/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux"  /usr/bin/make -j5  -C /media/justus_fluegel/PROJECTS/buildroot/buildroot-2019.11.1/output/build/dietsplash-v0.3/
make[1]: Entering directory '/media/justus_fluegel/PROJECTS/buildroot/buildroot-2019.11.1/output/build/dietsplash-v0.3'
/usr/bin/make  all-am
make[2]: Entering directory '/media/justus_fluegel/PROJECTS/buildroot/buildroot-2019.11.1/output/build/dietsplash-v0.3'
  GEN      src/background.h
/bin/bash: src/genstaticlogo: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
Makefile:1017: recipe for target 'src/background.h' failed
make[2]: *** [src/background.h] Error 126
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: Leaving directory '/media/justus_fluegel/PROJECTS/buildroot/buildroot-2019.11.1/output/build/dietsplash-v0.3'
Makefile:400: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/justus_fluegel/PROJECTS/buildroot/buildroot-2019.11.1/output/build/dietsplash-v0.3'
package/pkg-generic.mk:238: recipe for target '/media/justus_fluegel/PROJECTS/buildroot/buildroot-2019.11.1/output/build/dietsplash-v0.3/.stamp_built' failed
make: *** [/media/justus_fluegel/PROJECTS/buildroot/buildroot-2019.11.1/output/build/dietsplash-v0.3/.stamp_built] Error 2
```

And *file* of src/genstaticlogo

```
src/genstaticlogo: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 4.19.0, not stripped
```

I think the problem is that src/genstaticlogo is compiled for the target but executed by the Makefile.am during the build process. How do I tell make to compile src/genstaticlogo for the build machine and not for the target? Altough the repository is not my work, it's theoretically possible to modify the makefile after download.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to patch the Makefile.am to support cross-compilation. See [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201260/autotools-cross-compilation-and-generated-sources) for details. In short, you will need something like this in the Makefile.am:

```
$(genstaticlogo_OBJECTS): CC=$(CC_FOR_BUILD)
$(genstaticlogo_OBJECTS): CFLAGS=$(CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD)
$(genstaticlogo_OBJECTS): CPPFLAGS=$(CPPFLAGS_FOR_BUILD)
```

Since you will be patching Makefile.am, you will also need to set `DIETSPLASH_AUTORECONF = YES` in the Buildroot dietsplash.mk file.